# Can't open DevTools on NW 0.13 in Linux

Tags: linux, node-webkit

Since NW 0.13 I cannot open the devtools anymore.

According to offical [documentation](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Migration/From%200.12%20to%200.13/), it should be possible to open the DevTools in Linux by pressing `F12`.

I've tried `F12`, `ctrl+shift+J`, `ctrl+shift+I` but none of them is working. Is it a bug or am I doing wrong?

I'm on Gnome shell 3.20.2 and NW is 0.13.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my bad.... I was using the standard version of nw whereas you need the sdk version if you need the devtools.

Comment: How to use the sdk version? In my package json I have this - "nw":"0.20.1",
Where do I specify sdk verison